# ambiguous behaviour on ending program from task manager

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, taskmanager

I made a simple Windows application using WINAPI and then handled WM_CLOSE in its WinProc to display a message box asking confirmation from the user to confirm or cancel closing the window.

When simply clicking on cross button the application works fine but on ending the application from task manager it shows different behavior for model and non model message boxes.

On using a model message-box there is only one message box that pops up for user confirmation but on using non-model message-box two message boxes that pop up.

Why is it showing two dialog boxes????

Here is my code

```
case WM_CLOSE:
  if (MessageBox(NULL, "Do you want to quit","Exit",MB_OKCANCEL|MB_ICONQUESTION) == IDOK)
    PostQuitMessage (WM_QUIT);
  else
    ShowWindow (hWnd, SW_RESTORE);
  break;
```

The full code can be seen at

http://codepad.org/elkXnBM1

Comment: Since the dialog is non modal, Task Manager tries to close both the message box and the main window. Your code is wrong. If the user hits X twice, your app crashes.

Comment: @RaymondChen if the user clicks on X multiple times multiple message boxes pop up instead of the application crashing.And regarding your first arguement then if 4 message boxes are opened say then on ending the program through task manager should result in 5 more message boxes which is not the case

Comment: When the user clicks X multiple times and gets multiple message boxes, try dismissing the messages boxes in the wrong order. (You may not even notice the issue with the current code, especially since it just posts a quit message without properly cleaning up. But a more complex program that does proper cleanup will notice.)

Comment: @RaymondChen say if i open k message boxes and press ok or cancel on any of the k-1 message boxes nothing happens.Only if the last message box is provided an input(say cancel) an any one of the k-1 are provided an ok input application closes.If the k-1 are provided cancel and only last is provided an ok then also application closes

Comment: You don't notice the problem in the current code because you don't have a `WM_DESTROY` handler.